# AngularJS Unable to send JSON data to DB after adding redirect

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, database, ionic-framework

I am trying to send JSON data to a backend database. The following code works fine until I add a redirect into the newPost function using "$window.location.href = 'success.html';" After adding the redirect, nothing is posted to the database. There are also no errors displayed in console. I assume, I should probably be checking if the post was successful but am unsure of how to properly do that.

```
app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $window, getData, Post, randomString) {
   // Get all posts
   $scope.posts = Post.query();

  // Form data for creating a new post with ng-model
  $scope.postData = {};
    $scope.$on('updateImage', function () {
        $scope.postData.attachment = getData.image;
    });
    $scope.postData.userid = "Mango Farmer";
    $scope.postData.uuid = randomString(32);
    $scope.$on('updateGPS', function () {
        $scope.postData.gps = getData.gps;
    });
    $scope.postData.devicedate = $filter('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

  $scope.newPost = function() {
    var post = new Post($scope.postData);
    console.log(post);
    post.$save();
    $window.location.href = 'success.html';
  }

});
```

Successful Response from Server

```
RETURN CODE: 200
RETURN HEADERS:
Content-Type: application/json
RETURN BODY:
{
"ref":<string>,
"uuid":<string>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post.$save();
$window.location.href = 'success.html';
```

should be:

```
post.$save().then(function(response) {
    $window.location.href = 'success.html';
});
```

I'm pretty sure thats right. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!